# Prevent broken HTML from breaking table and page

Tags: php, html, tags

My problem is simple - I'm using PHP and grabbing data from a database using mysql. The data im grabbing is a long string of text - sometimes it could have HTML tags in it.

My problem is if the long string of text i'm grabbing contains broken HTML tags, like an anchor tag that doesn't close, it completely destroys the table when I print the string inside the td.

How can I ensure any text inside the td of the table will not break the table (while still rendering the HTML content)?

Comment: Fix what is _broken_?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your best bet would be [Tidy](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php).

```
<?php

$fragment = '<p>This is a broken string <a href="blah">on text';

$tidy = new tidy();

$tidy->parseString($fragment,array('show-body-only'=>true),'utf8');
$tidy->cleanRepair();

echo $tidy;
```